# How to request all insights for a page Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an application which will need to access multiple page insight metrics for a Facebook page.  However, rather than running multiple queries for the metrics that I would like, I was wondering if I could just request all of a page's insights.  I thought that to get that, I could just use:

```
{page-id}/insights
```

However this query returns a "FacebookAuthenticationException."  When I run this query on the Graph API Explorer, I get the user message "No metric specified."

So is there anyway to retrieve all of a page's insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that to get that, I could just use: `{page-id}/insights`

No, that is not possible any more.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_7_changes:

> **Page Insights Change** Page metrics insights must now be explicitly specified when making Page Insights related requests. The default behavior of returning all metrics when none are specified is no longer supported.

So you will have to pick the metrics you are interested in, and request those specifically:

```
{page-id}/insights/metric_name1,metric_name2,...
```